# Convert a string to base64

Tags: encoding, base64, rust

I need a simple thing: encode a string in base64. I found an example:

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::base64::{mod, ToBase64};
use serialize::hex::FromHex;

fn main() {
    let input = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
    let result = input.from_hex().unwrap().as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Which **seams** to work but I don't understand why input contains only characters in HEX. Moreover, this Python code produces a different result:

```
base64.b64encode(input) # =>
'NDkyNzZkMjA2YjY5NmM2YzY5NmU2NzIwNzk2Zjc1NzIyMDYyNzI2MTY5NmUyMDZjNjk2YjY1MjA2MTIwNzA2ZjY5NzM2ZjZlNmY3NTczMjA2ZDc1NzM2ODcyNmY2ZjZk'
```

So I decided to do the following:

```
  //....
    let input = "some string 123";
    let result2 = input.unwrap().as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
    let result3 = input.as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
```

And it didn't compile due to the errors:

```
error: type `&str` does not implement any method in scope named `unwrap`
test1.rs:9     let result2 = input.unwrap().as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
                                   ^~~~~~~~
test1.rs:9:34: 9:44 error: multiple applicable methods in scope [E0034]
```

So how do I encode a simple string in base64?

Comment: I think you’re not understanding some critical things—in order to call `unwrap` on an object, it must be of a type that *has* an `unwrap` method. `Option<T>`, for example. But `input` is not an `Option`, it’s just a plain `&'static str`. You can go looking at [the documentation of `from_hex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/hex/trait.FromHex.html#tymethod.from_hex) and so forth to understand what these things are doing.

Comment: My comment is in all seriousness, addressing the problems I see in the question. What you have written suggests very strongly to me that there are several things you don’t understand, so I’m directing you in the way to learn them.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, so what of it?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: You are being cryptic and I am unable to determine your meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have hex input, try this:

```
let result = input.as_bytes().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
```

Comment: by the way, why doesn't it produce the value with "==" at the end?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp It does. Try it online on play.rust-lang.org: http://is.gd/Fql04O (you can add a hyphen to the URL to get a preview as confirmation that it goes to rust-lang.org). There I get a value ending in `==`.

Comment: I understood, it depends on the length of the string.

Comment: by the way, how do I convert it back to string "using" UTF-8?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp If you want to convert back to a string, you can remove the `mod,` from the `use serialize::...`, and if `input` contains your Base64 value, use this code: `let a = input.from_base64(); let b = a.unwrap(); let c = b.as_slice(); let result = std::str::from_utf8(c).unwrap();` (yes, you need to create all those variables, otherwise Rust gives an error that the variable lifetime is not long enough).

Answer (score 2):

`to_base64` is only defined for a slice of bytes so you have to first call `as_bytes` on the string:

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::base64::{mod, ToBase64};

fn main() {
    let input = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
    let result = input.as_bytes().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Input has the type `&static str`:

```
let input = "some string 123";
```

There is no unwrap defined for `&'static str`:

```
let result2 = input.unwrap().as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
```

You already have a slice (`&str`) but you need `&[u8]`:

```
let result3 = input.as_slice().to_base64(base64::STANDARD);
```